# Java-Stream - Grouping Lists based on several elements within each List

Tags: java, java-stream, treemap, collectors

I have the following data stored as lists:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> dummy = new ArrayList<>();
dummy.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("1", "SP1", "SW1")));
dummy.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("2", "SP1", "SW2")));
dummy.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("3", "SP2", "SW1")));
dummy.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("4", "SP2", "SW2")));
dummy.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("5", "SP2", "SW1")));
dummy.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("6", "SP1", "SW1")));
dummy.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("7", "SP3", "SW2")));
```

I need to group it as follows

```
SW1-SP1-list{1,6}  
SW1-SP2-list{3,5}  
SW2-SP1-list{2}   
SW2-SP2-list{4}    
SW2-SP3-list{7}
```

What I have tried is the following:

```
var test = dummy.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        s -> s.get(2),
        TreeMap::new,
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            s -> s.get(1),
            Collectors.toList()
        )
    ));
```

But this doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: What is the result data structure? Do you want it to be nested map? `SW1` in outer map and `SP1` as nested map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can apply nested groupingBy

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> result = dummy.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l.get(2),
                Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l.get(1),
                        Collectors.mapping(l -> l.get(0), Collectors.toList()))));
```

To collect it in the order encountered, you can use a `LinkedHashMap`,

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> result = dummy.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l.get(2), LinkedHashMap::new,
                Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l.get(1), LinkedHashMap::new,
                        Collectors.mapping(l -> l.get(0), Collectors.toList()))));
System.out.println(result);
```

Result:

```
{SW1={SP1=[1, 6], SP2=[3, 5]}, SW2={SP1=[2], SP2=[4], SP3=[7]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nested Maps are impractical because they are not very convenient.

And since you basically need to associate every distinct combination of `SW` and `SP` with a corresponding list of values, you can define an auxiliary object that would serve as a *key*.

That would allow to achieve the desired result without a need to resort to nested maps.

A Java 16 [**record**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/records.html) would fit into this role perfectly well (if you're using a lower version of JDK, you can implement it as a plain class):

```
record SwSp(String sw, String sp) {}
```

In order to use it as a *key* in a `TreeMap` it needs either implement `Comparable` interface, or you can provide a `Comparator`  while creating a `TreeMap` as shown below.

To generate comparator you can use Java 8 static methods [`comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) and [`thenComparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.function.Function)).

With it, the stream might look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String>> dummy = List.of(
        new ArrayList<>(List.of("1", "SP1", "SW1")),
        new ArrayList<>(List.of("2", "SP1", "SW2")),
        new ArrayList<>(List.of("3", "SP2", "SW1")),
        new ArrayList<>(List.of("4", "SP2", "SW2")),
        new ArrayList<>(List.of("5", "SP2", "SW1")),
        new ArrayList<>(List.of("6", "SP1", "SW1")),
        new ArrayList<>(List.of("7", "SP3", "SW2"))
    );

    NavigableMap<SwSp, List<String>> test = dummy.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            list -> new SwSp(list.get(2), list.get(1)),
            () -> new TreeMap<>(
                Comparator.comparing(SwSp::sw).thenComparing(SwSp::sp)
            ),
            Collectors.mapping(list -> list.get(0),
                Collectors.toList())
        ));
    
    test.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
}
```

*Output:*

```
SwSp[sw=SW1, sp=SP1] -> [1, 6]
SwSp[sw=SW1, sp=SP2] -> [3, 5]
SwSp[sw=SW2, sp=SP1] -> [2]
SwSp[sw=SW2, sp=SP2] -> [4]
SwSp[sw=SW2, sp=SP3] -> [7]
```

**Note**

Based on the way how these lists are structured (they all have exactly `3` elements which are ordered in the same way) I can make a conclusion that you're misusing collections because your `List` of `List`s should be a `List` of objects in the first place.